# Use Composite Primary Key as Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, constraints

How can I use a composite primary key as a foreign key? It looks like my attempt does not work.

```
create table student
(
student_id varchar (25) not null ,
student_name varchar (50) not null ,
student_pone int ,
student_CNIC varchar (50),
students_Email varchar (50),
srudents_address varchar(250),
dept_id varchar(6),
batch_id varchar(4),
FOREIGN KEY (dept_id) REFERENCES department(dept_id),
FOREIGN KEY (batch_id) REFERENCES batch(batch_id),
CONSTRAINT pk_studentID PRIMARY KEY (batch_id,dept_id,student_id) )
```

---

```
create table files
(
files_name varchar(50) not null ,
files_path varchar(50),
files_data varchar(max),
files_bookmarks xml ,
FOREIGN KEY (pk_studentID ) REFERENCES student(pk_studentID ),
CONSTRAINT pk_filesName PRIMARY KEY (files_name) )
```

Comment: How to Use Composite Primary Key as Foreign Key

Comment: @Paul Bellora I added the question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The line:

```
FOREIGN KEY (pk_studentID ) REFERENCES student(pk_studentID ),
```

is wrong. You can't use `pk_studentID` like that, this is just the name of the PK constraint in the parent table. To use a compound Primary Key as Foreign Key, you'll have to add the same number of columns (that compose the PK) with same datatypes to the child table and then use the combination of these columns in the `FOREIGN KEY` definition:

```
CREATE TABLE files
(
  files_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, 

  batch_id varchar(4) NOT NULL,         --- added, these 3 should not
  dept_id varchar(6) NOT NULL,          --- necessarily be NOT NULL
  student_id varchar (25) NOT NULL,     --- 

  files_path varchar(50),
  files_data varchar(max),              --- varchar(max) ??   
  files_bookmarks xml,                  --- xml ??
                                        --- your question is tagged MySQL, 
                                        --- and not SQL-Server

  CONSTRAINT pk_filesName 
    PRIMARY KEY (files_name),

  CONSTRAINT fk_student_files                     --- constraint name (optional)
    FOREIGN KEY (batch_id, dept_id, student_id)  
      REFERENCES student (batch_id, dept_id, student_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

Comment: Also, the order is important.

Comment: You have saved me a *lot* of trouble; this really isn't clear from the docs.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Jus12, you saved me a lot of troubleshooting time :)