# How to add composite primary key as foreign key in wamp server?

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

I'm facing problem while dealing with composite primary keys to be referenced as foreign keys in wamp server. I have done this :

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    category INT NOT NULL, id INT NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL,
    PRIMARY KEY(category, id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE customer (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE product_order (
    no INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product_category INT NOT NULL,
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(no),
    INDEX (product_category, product_id),
    INDEX (customer_id),

    FOREIGN KEY (product_category, product_id)
      REFERENCES product(category, id)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,

    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
      REFERENCES customer(id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Now, when I open phpmyadmin, foreign key for product is not shown. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565846/use-composite-primary-key-as-foreign-key

Comment: Yes. But it didn't help, as the answer they provided is of the same form as my question. I am still facing problem