# MS Access SQL Query ADD Foreign Key

Tags: sql, ms-access

We're having trouble with adding a foreign key constraint with SQL in MS Access. We're trying to add a composite key as a foreign key. Underneath you'll find our SQL-statement:

```
ALTER TABLE ARTICLE (
ADD CONSTRAINT rackSort_FK
FOREIGN KEY (rackSort) 
REFERENCES ARTICLE(rackSize, rackType)
);
```

Do you see any mistakes? Why doesn't this work?
Access shows the following error:

> Syntax error in ALTER TABLE statement.

Thanks in advance!
Greets,
Sytze & Tom

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a foreign key from ARTICLE to ARTICLE?

Answer (score 2):

Close, just remove parentheses.

```
ALTER TABLE ARTICLE 
ADD CONSTRAINT rackSort_FK
FOREIGN KEY (rackSort) 
REFERENCES ARTICLE(rackSize, rackType)
;
```

But the number of columns must be the same and match! `(rackSort)` is just one, but  `(rackSize, rackType)` are two columns... You have to change that!!!

Also consider Andre451's comment above, do you really want to create a self-referencing foreign key?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We already altered the statement to avoid a self-referencing foreign key; that wasn't supposed to be like that. However, even by altering the statement it still doesn't work... rackSize and rackType form a composite key: they're both primary keys. Therefore, we want the primary (composite) key of rackSize and rackType to reference to another column named rackSort. Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you add both table definitions to the question? No, two columns can never be a FK referencing only 1 column.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add same no. of columns as foreign keys.

This may help you:

[Add Composite Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565846/use-composite-primary-key-as-foreign-key)