# MySQL error:1251 cannot add foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1064

The first 4 table are created fine, the transactions tables run into problem. I get the 1215 error: cannot add foreign key. I've checked an rechecked the data types, and made sure all FK are PK of their own tables. What's wrong here?

```
CREATE SCHEMA FinalDB;

CREATE TABLE `User` (
    userId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    first_name varchar(255) not null,
    last_name varchar(255) not null,
    address varchar(255) null,
    DOB date not null,
    availableBalance int not null default 0,
    currency varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Verifications(
    userId int not null primary key,
    passport int null,
    ssn int null,
    license int null,
    constraint
    foreign key (userId)
    references User(userId)
);

CREATE TABLE Linked_Account(
    account_Id int not null, 
    userId int not null,
    routing int null,
    swift int null,
    primary key (userId, account_Id),
    constraint
    foreign key (userId) 
    references User(userId)
);

CREATE TABLE Wallet (
    userId int not null,
    walletId varchar(5) not null,
    coinAmount int not null default 0,
    netWorth int not null default 0,
    primary key(userId, walletId),
    constraint
    foreign key (userId)
    references `User`(userId)
);

CREATE TABLE Transactions (
    transactionId int not null primary key auto_increment, 
    userId int not null,
    type varchar(30) not null,
    walletId varchar(5) not null,
    payment_method int null, #optional
    total int null, #optional
    quantity int not null,
    fee int null, #optional
    `date` date not null,
    sender varchar(50) null, #optional
    reciever varchar(50) null, #optional
    status varchar(20) not null,
    notes varchar(200) null, #optional
    constraint 
    foreign key (userId)
    references `User`(userId) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    constraint 
    foreign key (walletId)
    references Wallet(walletId)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    constraint
    foreign key (payment_method)
    references Linked_Account(account_id)

);

CREATE TABLE TransactionsExchange(
    transactionId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    userId int not null,
    currencyFrom int not null,
    currencyFromAmount int not null,
    currencyInto int not null,
    currencyIntoEquivalent int not null,
    notes varchar(200) null,
    `date` date not null,
    constraint
    foreign key (userId)
    references User(userId),
    constraint
    foreign key (currencyFrom)
    references Wallet(walletId),
    constraint
    foreign key (currencyInto)
    references Wallet(walletId)
);
```

I've look online for possible answer, but it's usually having to do with inconsistent data types or undeclared PK's. I'm basically trying to make a transactions table to log various different data in different compositions. Using backend logic to handle what is required and what is not, aside from a few defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To use a compound Primary Key as Foreign Key, you'll have to add the
>   same number of columns (that compose the PK) with same datatypes to
>   the child table and then use the combination of these columns in the
>   FOREIGN KEY definition.

see related post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10566463/4904726

Try this 'Transactions' table creating query:

```
 CREATE TABLE Transactions (
            transactionId int not null primary key auto_increment, 
            userId int not null,
            type varchar(30) not null,
            walletId varchar(5) not null,
            payment_method int null, #optional
            total int null, #optional
            quantity int not null,
            fee int null, #optional
            `date` date not null,
            sender varchar(50) null, #optional
            reciever varchar(50) null, #optional
            status varchar(20) not null,
            notes varchar(200) null, #optional
            constraint 
            foreign key (userId)
            references `User`(userId) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            constraint
            foreign key (userId, walletId)
            references Wallet(userId, walletId)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            constraint
            foreign key (userId, payment_method)
            references Linked_Account(userId, account_id)

        );
```

Comment: That worked nicely! I never up to now had to import composite keys as foreign keys. I just assumed each key would have to be declared individually. Thanks!