# #1005 - Can't create table `agenceassurance`.`operation` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, create-table

errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS AgenceAssurance;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS AgenceAssurance;
USE AgenceAssurance;

CREATE TABLE Logininfo (
  idLogin    INT(3)  PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userName       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  pass       VARCHAR(50),
  usertype   VARCHAR(50)          DEFAULT NULL,
  GrantedKey VARCHAR(8)           DEFAULT NULL
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Operation (
  idOpt    INT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  libelOpt TEXT,
  dateOpt  DATETIME DEFAULT now(),
  userName VARCHAR(50),
   CONSTRAINT fk_login FOREIGN KEY (userName) REFERENCES Logininfo (userName)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Error**
*SQL query:*

```
CREATE TABLE Operation (
  idOpt    INT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  libelOpt TEXT,
  dateOpt  DATETIME DEFAULT now(),
  userName VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT fk_login FOREIGN KEY (userName) REFERENCES Logininfo (userName)
)ENGINE = InnoDB
```

*MySQL said:*

## 1005 - Can't create table `agenceassurance`.`operation` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Comment: In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html - not something your fk has

Comment: how i can correct that

Comment: You have composite primary key and you are using one of the column for foreign key Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565846/use-composite-primary-key-as-foreign-key?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: please check the changes above

Comment: @KedarLimaye i have made only one Primery key i altered the table to add the foreign key Separately

Answer (score 0):

**CONSTRAINT pk_Log PRIMARY KEY (idLogin, userName):**
try as below:
CONSTRAINT pk_Log PRIMARY KEY (userName)
because: at a time two fields with PK, cannot use as FK.

Comment: i have made some changes to only one PRIMERY KEY and, still have the same problem

Comment: can u share 2 sql

Comment: table should be ENGINE = InnoDB ;

Comment: please check the changes above

Comment: You should set pk for userName instead of idLogin. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

The field **userName** in **Logininfo** table must be UNIQUE. You can only have a foreign key referencing a unique field.

Just like this:

```
userName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
```