# Would you create a composite primary key or a normal primary key if a 'Full Address' is the main identifier

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

Context: I've been creating a database for a class assignment, the assignment doesn't have detailed instructions, instead gives us a narrative in order to have us make our own assumptions and interpretations as to what to create for the database. Essentially a database that has employees and a factory. Factories are identified using their **Full Address** ,and have several other attributes.

I essentially have the entire ERD modeled and MYSQL code drafted based on my interpretation of the narrative, however I'm having zero clue on what to do with the "Full Address" identifier. Considering it says that its a "full address", my two main assumptions are either this:

I create a composite primary key with Street Number, Road, City, etc.

Or I make a varchar primary key that simply has the address as a string variable and nothing much.
This is what I have originally, but I'm having second thoughts.

```
CREATE table factory
( address VARCHAR(100),
  yearbuilt INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (address)
);
```

If I should make a composite primary key for this table, how would I code a composite primary key for a full address in MYSQL?, and how would I code this as a foreign key for other tables?

Comment: opinion is called for. I wouldn't use address, I would use an auto-incrementing integer. This about foreign keys, do you really want to join tables via address? Street names can be changed too. All sorts of issues in an address.

Comment: Like I could either do a simple VARCHAR address which would be way easier to implement as a primary key and a foreign key for any of the tables that need it or I could just do a composite key which makes it way more complicated. Probably gonna with my original plan to be honest

Comment: Don't use natural keys, but synthetic ones (auto generated number). In the real world natural keys are never unique.

Comment: You could use a surrogate key such as an auto-incrementing integer, while also, placing a unique constraint on the address field, if that is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Why bother splitting `address` into parts `Street Number, Road, City`?  Do you ever search on any of those fields?  Or sort by them?  Maybe postal_code (zip_code) is useful to keep separate.

Answer (score 1):

How to make composite primary key and make it foreign key for other table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10566463/22890637

But that will make it harder for you in production. I agree with Adrian to make an auto-incrementing integer column. It would yield in better result and easier to manage data.

If you thinking about making faster query by using composite primary key, it would be better to use [multiple columns index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

It's your decision, you do what suits your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

If you use it in other tables  as foreign key as well, i would suggest you use a separate column as primary key, because referencing composite keys as foreign keys can be a pain.

I also would advice to let more room for address as 100 chars, when the data can be input online by people, and there are possibilities address is bigger than 100 chars. ofc. if you have only a closed source file that is all in, then it doesnt matter.

in many databases you can use something like AUTO_INCREMENT for having an primary key filled easy.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to force the address to be unique? Are you going to use it in another table as a foreign key?

Another thing to consider is foreign characters as well which NVARCHAR() can help with as well. Address can get kinda long I would recommend 255 chars.

Being able to have an AUTO_INCREMENT is also handy as well from a maintenance stand-point. Otherwise you have to find the next value each time before adding a new one.